# NameError when printing string's length based on input in python

Tags: python

I'm a complete beginner in Python and I need some 'help' with something which is relatively simple (for a non-beginner).

What I'm trying to make is a quick 'program' which measures the length of a string which has been inputted. Maybe I have not looked hard enough, but I can't seem to find any *specific* information about this on the interwebs.

Ok, so here is what I have done so far:

```
print "Please enter a number or word and I will tell you the length of it."

NR = raw_input()
print len(NR)
```

*NR has no significant meaning, it's just a random variable name

Everything works as expected at first. For example, I enter the word "Hello" and it then replies with "5" or I enter the number 100 and it replies with "3" which is great, but when I attempt to enter another word I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    hello
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

However, when I enter another number (after I have already entered one), it just repeats the number which I have entered. For example, when I first enter the number "50" it replies with "2", but when I enter "50" a second time it just repeats the integer to me.

Note:
 *I think* I understand the problem for the first part: It doesn't work more than once because the variable "NR" only counts as the first string which has been inputted. Even if I'm correct, I still don't know a solution to this.

Comment: Please choose a question title that reflects the question content.

Comment: Are you calling the code via command line like this : `python file.py` ?

Comment: The title is not a question.

Comment: your name error is from the shell you are running in.  Your program is already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program collects exactly one line of input and then finishes. After your program is finished, you are back in whatever environment you used to start your program. If that environment is a python shell, then you should expect that typing `50` will print a `50`, and typing `hello` will print a no-such-variable-name error message.

To get your code to run more than once, put it in a while loop:

```
while True:
    print "Please enter a number or word and I will tell you the length of it."

    NR = raw_input()
    print len(NR)
```

Note that `raw_input()` can print a prompt, so you don't need the `print` statement:

```
while True:
    NR = raw_input("Please enter a number or word and I will tell you the length of it: ")
    print len(NR)
```

This program fragment will run forever (or, at least until you interrupt it with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>).

If you'd like to be able to stop without interrupting the program, try this:

```
NR = None
while NR != '':
    NR = raw_input("Please enter a number or word (or a blank line to exit): ")
    print len(NR)
```

---

If you'd like to print the prompt once and then the use can enter many strings, try this:

```
print "Please enter a number or word and I will tell you the length of it."
while True:
    NR = raw_input()
    print len(NR)
```

Comment: Your first paragraph is spot on.  I can duplicate his error message verbatim by running from IDLE.  Create the three line program.  Save.  F5 to run.  Then after first successful run the error message occurs because his program is over and he is in the interactive shell.

Comment: Just what I wanted. But is there a way to stop it from constantly repeating "Please enter a number or word and I will tell you the length of it." each time?

Comment: @Smarzey : Yes. Go with the first code fragment in my answer, but move the `print` statement to above the `while` loop. That way, the `print` runs exacty once, but the `raw_input` runs many times. Don't forget to adjust the indentation, or you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: @Smarzey , I was unclear in my instructions. Please see my most recent edit.

Comment: Works perfectly now thanks! Excuse me for my stupidity, I moved "print len(NR)" instead of the other. It seems that I had forgotten what a statement was when I read your comment haha.